# spring security java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to use Spring security guard and I have mostly figured it out but after trying for a long time I can not fix this error. I have this error when I log in:

```
    exception 
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception


    root cause 
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.changeSessionId(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:290)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.changeSessionId(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:290)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:196)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:181)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.applySessionFixation(ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.AbstractSessionFixationProtectionStrategy.onAuthentication(AbstractSessionFixationProtectionStrategy.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:216)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I do not know exactly what to write in the code, this is what I have:

```
<properties>
            <spring.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        </properties>
     <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>myfaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>myfaces</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.9</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                <version>1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
                <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.11</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                <version>6.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>6.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.6</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

> 

```
<!--                                    Spring Security       -->
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
            access-denied-page="/acsesDenied.jsp">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
             login-processing-url="/login" username-parameter="username"
             password-parameter="password" default-target-url="/welcome.form"
             always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=invalidLogin"/>

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome.form" access="isAuthenticated"/>

        <security:logout logout-url="/logout"/>
        <security:remember-me user-service-ref="userService" key="q_key"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
            <security:password-encoder ref="passwordHncoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
        <property name="rolePrefix" value=""/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Can youfix the stacktrace. No AbstractMethodError is visible.

Comment: Sorry did not see that did not copy all,update stacktrace

Comment: it started working after I cleared the Lib folder in Tomcat

Comment: I had same issue, I was having `servlet-api.jar` and `javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar` in my tomcat/lib folder after i removed `javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar` it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You seems to have a version conflict of Servlet API.

These are bad dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The servlet container (like Tomcat) includes a version of Servlet API, but the dependencies above includes them also, with a rather old version. Try to remove these dependencies. If you need them during compile, you can set as provided:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I had the same problem and the cause was a javaee-api.jar inside tomcat/lib folder. Removing that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to help anyone (it is not a solution, but perhaps may serve as a clue), but I faced the same problems when running the app in an embedded tomcat container. On deploying the same app into a stand-alone tomcat container, the problem went away. Embedded tomcat, maven plugin:

```
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
```

Stand-alone tomcat version:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.53
Server built:   Mar 25 2014 06:20:16
Server number:  7.0.53.0
OS Name:        Linux
```

Still trying to figure out the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and found out the solution.This is due to javax.servlet.api.jar is imported by some other dependencies in your POM.XML before spring.starter.security dependency.Find that dependency and add

```
 <exclusion>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
 </exclusion>
```

Then add this below dependency after your spring-boot-starter-security dependency.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Try this out before doing other suggestions?